# what's the main difference between List interface and Collection Interface?

Tags: java, list, collections

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between List (of T) and Collection(of T)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398903/what-is-the-difference-between-list-of-t-and-collectionof-t)
>   [What is the difference between Collection and List in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317381/what-is-the-difference-between-collection-and-list-in-java)

Is there any pros/cons of using one again the other? what's main advantage to use Collection rather than List?

Comment: The documentation would answer this question rather effectively: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html.  I quote: *[a List is] an **ordered collection** (also known as a sequence). The user of this interface has precise **control over where in the list each element is inserted.** The user can **access elements by their integer index** (position in the list), and **search for elements** in the list..*

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "use Collection rather than List"?  How were you planning on instantiating the collection?  What concrete implementation would you be evaluating?

Comment: Sorry, accidentally cast my close vote for a .NET question. Should have been: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317381/what-is-the-difference-between-collection-and-list-in-java

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the List interface allows you to do operations involving indexes (positions): retrieve the element in a given index, delete an element in an index, insert an element, etc.

A Collection is a more general interface, with more classes implementing it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [the JavaDocs for List](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

A lot of them have lines like this, showing that they're from the `Collection` interface:

> Specified by:
>
> ```
> size in interface Collection<E>
> ```

The ones with no "specified by" section are:

```
E get(int index)

E set(int index,
      E element)

void add(int index,
         E element)

E remove(int index)

int indexOf(Object o)

int lastIndexOf(Object o)

ListIterator<E> listIterator()

ListIterator<E> listIterator(int index)

List<E> subList(int fromIndex,
                int toIndex)
```

Where `E` is the `Type` specified in `List<Type>`.

Basically, it's a bunch of things related to indexes -- because not all `Collections` have an index, or an order at all for that matter, and a couple related to special iterators, and `subList`.

The advantage to using `Collection` in method signatures is that you don't force your users to use one kind of collection (some users can use a `Set`, some can use a `List`, etc.). This only makes sense if you don't need the methods that `List gives you.

In this example, I'm not using any `List`-specific methods:

```
/**
 * Simple example, adds "1" to the Collection
 */
public static void addOne(Collection in) {
    in.add(1);
}
```

There's no reason to force users of this method to only pass it a list, because the only method we're calling on it (`add`) is available in all `Collection`s.

Answer (score 0):

A [List](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) *is a* [Collection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html), but it adds the concept of having element *order*.
In addition to the methods of Collection, List's also have these methods:

- public boolean addAll(int index, Collection c)
- public E get(int index)
- public E set(int index, E element)
- public void add(int index, E element)
- public E remove(int index)
- public int indexOf(Object o)
- public int lastIndexOf(Object o)
- public ListIterator listIterator()
- public ListIterator listIterator(int index)
- public List subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex)

In general,

- Use a List when order matters, and/or duplicates are OK. ArrayList is a good choice.
- Use a Set when order doesn't matter and when duplicates are not OK. HashSet is a good choice.
- Use a LinkedHashSet when order *does* matter and duplicates are not OK