# What are the major differences between a Collection, an ArrayList, and a List in Java?

Tags: java

An ArrayList, a List and a Collection in Java behaves almost in the same way and they have many methods in common. If such is a case then, what are the major differences among them? The following simple code snippet demonstrates it.

```
package collections;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

final public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Collection<String> collection=new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String>list=new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String>arrayList=new ArrayList<String>();        

        collection.add("A");
        collection.add("B");

        list.add("A");
        list.add("B");

        arrayList.add("A");
        arrayList.add("B");

        Iterator<String>collectionIterator=collection.iterator();
        Iterator<String>listIterator=list.iterator();
        Iterator<String>arrayListIterator=arrayList.iterator();

        while(collectionIterator.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println(collectionIterator.next());
        }

        while(listIterator.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println(listIterator.next());
        }

        while(arrayListIterator.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println(arrayListIterator.next());
        }
    }
}
```

---

When and where to use an ArrayList, a Collection and a List? In which specific situations, the differences among them may be remarkable?

Comment: Maybe he knows so much that he thinks the question is not useful... don't get personal by taking it personal. Anyways, your question can probably answered by a couple of other questions, such as [What is the difference between Collection and List in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317381/what-is-the-difference-between-collection-and-list-in-java) and [What is a List vs. an ArrayList?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867484/java-what-is-a-list-vs-an-arraylist).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A `Collection` is an interface that defines the highest-level of shared collection behavior, and extends `Iterable` (which just defines the `iterator()` method).

A `List` is an interface that defines the highest-level of shared `List` behavior.

`ArrayList` is an *implementation* of `List` and in general wouldn't be used in a *declaration* unless you need an implementation guarantee (e.g., fast indexed access), but is fine to use as a list *value*.

Read the docs to see the differences–they're described in the API. The implementation (`ArrayList`) will have a type-specific implementation of each method in each interface it implements.

In general, use the *least*-specific interface that provides what you need. For example, passing `Collection` instead of `List` allows a wider selection of implementations. If you need something like indexed access (e.g., `List.get(int)`), a `Collection` wouldn't work.

As with most things, which to use depends entirely upon your needs.

Answer (score 9):

For local variables, it does not really matter. It does matter when the type is part of an API, i.e. in a method signature that might be called by code not yet written:

- The type `Collection` has a very simple contract - it implies basically only that you have a bunch of elements, you can add and remove elements, check whether the collections contains a specific element, and iterate over them. If that's all your code needs, use `Collection` - it gives the code that uses your API the greatest freedom.
- The type `List` has in its contract that the elements have an order that will not change except through explicit manipulation, that you can `get()` the n'th element, that `add()` puts new elements at the end, etc. If your code depends on any of these properties, you should use `List`
- `ArrayList` is just a concrete implementation of `List` and should never be used in an API. Its usage should only ever be an implementation detail (unless you have some very specific requirements).

Not thinking carefully about the types used in an API can lead to a lot of pointless conversions and unnecessarily slow code as collections are converted between `Collection`, `Set`, `List` and various implementation classes just to satisfy badly designed APIs.

Answer (score 3):

`ArrayList` is an implementation, `Collection` and `List` are interfaces.

`Collection` is the somewhat super-interface, with `List` as a specialisation (ordered `Collection`). `ArrayList` is a implementation of `List` (resizable array).

See the [Java Tutorials, Trail: Collections, Implementations](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

You're using an `ArrayList` in all 3 cases.
To further explain, `Collection<String> collection=new ArrayList<String>();` could be re-written as,

```
Collection<String> collection;
collection = new ArrayList<String>();
```

The first statement defines a variable of type `Collection<String>` named `collection` while the second statement creates a `new ArrayList<String>()` and assigns it to `collection`.

The compiler allows assigning an `ArrayList<String>` to `Collection<String>` because `ArrayList` [is-a](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) `Collection` i.e. all ArrayLists are Collections because they implement the [Collection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) [interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_%28Java%29). The inverse is obviously not true, all Collections are definitely not ArrayLists.

Answer (score 1):

`Collection` and `List` are interfaces. `ArrayList` is a class. We cannot `new Collection()` or `new List()`.  But we can `new ArrayList()`.

`Collection` has no concept of index. `List` and `ArrayList` has a method that can set/get using an index.  For example, `Collection` has `add(object)`.  `List` and `ArrayList` have `add(object)` and `add(index, object)`.