# SortedList that maintains order like SortedSet but also permits duplicate elements

Tags: java, list, sorting

I want to order a list every time a new element is added. My approach is to override the add method and add the sorting of my list. But I think this looks funny. Is their a better way to do this?

```
public class Test extends TestCase {
    List<String> superlist = new ArrayList<String>() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public boolean add(String e) {
            boolean erg = super.add(e);
            Comparator<String> comp = (o1, o2) -> {
                return o1.compareTo(o2);
            };
            Collections.sort(this, comp);
            return erg;
        };
    };

    public void test() {
        superlist.add("A");
        superlist.add("Z");
        superlist.add("D");
        superlist.add("X");
        superlist.add("C");
        System.out.println(superlist); // [A, C, D, X, Z]
    }
}
```

Update
You could write a class, that extends ArrayList and compare every time a element is added. I think that's nicer

Comment: Java collections do not, AFAIK, support any sorted list.  But, there is a sorted set.  Why do you think that a list is the best data structure for your problem?

Comment: I choose a list because i have dublicated entries and i want to distinguish between the implementation [A, C, D, X, Z] and [A, A, C, D, X, Z].


And i think a sorted set is also a collection: [Link 3317381](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317381/what-is-the-difference-between-collection-and-list-in-java)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is there no SortedList in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725387/why-is-there-no-sortedlist-in-java) The accepted answer explains why it doesn't exist and presents several different ways to implement it yourself.